# @font-faceのlocalに指定すべき文字列を知るには？

Tags: css, font, postscript

CSS の [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) の `src` には `url()` の他に `local()` を指定することができます。たとえば `src: local("ＭＳ ゴシック")` と書けばローカルのMSゴシックを指定できます。

ここで、手元にある有名でないフォントについて、`local` に指定する名前をどう知れば良いのか知らないことに気付きました。[CSS Fonts Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule) には

> For OpenType and TrueType fonts, this string is used to match only the Postscript name or the full font name in the name table of locally available fonts.

と書かれているのですが、この Postscript name と full font name をどのようにすれば調べられるのかが分かりません。先の文書には続けて「どっちの名前を使うかは決まってないから両方書いてね」のように書かれており、Postscript name も full font name も両方知りたいです。

手元にある OpenType フォントや TrueType フォントについて、`local` に指定すべき名前である Postscript name と full font name を知るにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

環境は Windows 10 Home でお願いします。cmd.exe、PowerShell、WSL Ubuntu の Bash、その他必要なソフトウェアの使用は自由です。

<sub>※文脈：自分の持っているパソコン2台の上で動かす小さなウェブアプリを作っており、その2台ともにインストールされているフォントを `@font-face` で指定したくなり、できれば `src` ではなく `local` で指定できると嬉しいなとなってこの質問に至りました。</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんが引用した文章によれば、名前テーブル中に Postscript 名および完全なフォント名は含まれているように読めます。その直後には Postscript 名は名前テーブル内の **`nameID` が 6** の行に、完全なフォント名は **`nameID` が 4** の行に格納されている、と書かれています<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule)</sup>。また、 [name - Naming table specification - Typography | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-records) にも同様の内容がより詳細に書かれています。

> #### 4.3. Font reference: the src descriptor<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-face-rule)</sup>
>
> Just as a `@font-face` rule specifies the characteristics of a single font within a family, the unique name used with `local()` specifies a single font, not an entire font family. Defined in terms of OpenType font data, **the Postscript name is found in the font's name table, in the name record with `nameID = 6`** (see [OPENTYPE] for more details). The Postscript name is the commonly used key for all fonts on OSX and for Postscript CFF fonts under Windows. **The full font name (`nameID = 4`) is used as a unique key for fonts with TrueType glyphs on Windows.**

[LCDF Typetools](https://www.lcdf.org/type/index.html#typetools) の otfinfo で OpenType および TrueType フォントに関する情報を得ることが出来ます。`otfinfo` コマンドに `--info` オプションを付与することで Postscript 名および完全なフォント名が得られます。たとえば、 `GreatVibes-Regular.otf`, `ARIAL.ttf` に対して `otfinfo` コマンドを実行すると、以下のような結果が得られました。

```
C:\Users\supa>otfinfo -i GreatVibes-Regular.otf
Family:              Great Vibes
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Great Vibes
PostScript name:     GreatVibes-Regular
Version:             Version 1.001
Unique ID:           RobertE.Leuschke: Great Vibes: 2012
Designer:            Robert E. Leuschke
Designer URL:        www.typesetit.com
Manufacturer:        Robert E. Leuschke
Trademark:           Grerat Vibes is a trademark of Robert E. Leuschke.
with Reserved Font Name "Great Vibes"12 TypeSETit, LLC (typesetit@att.net),
License URL:         http://scripts.sil.org/OFL
License Description: This Font Software is licensed under the SIL Open Font License, Version 1.1. This license is available with a FAQ at: http://scripts.sil.org/OFL.
Vendor ID:           pyrs
```

```
C:\Users\supa>otfinfo -i ARIAL.ttf
Family:              Arial
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Arial
PostScript name:     ArialMT
Version:             Version 7.00
Unique ID:           Monotype:Arial Regular (Microsoft)
Designer:            Monotype Type Drawing Office - Robin Nicholas, Patricia Saunders 1982
Manufacturer:        The Monotype Corporation
Trademark:           Arial is a trademark of The Monotype Corporation.
Copyright:           © 2017 The Monotype Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

Comment: フォントに詳しくないので最適な方法かはわかりませんが、おそらく  [Font Forge](https://fontforge.org/) などのツールを用いることでも Postscript 名、完全なフォント名を得られると思います。

Comment: (1) 私の環境では cmd.exe でも Bash でも ttfdump コマンドが見つからなかったのですが、ここでいう ttfdump コマンドとはどこからインストールできるものを指してらっしゃいますか？　検索すると[このURL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/tools/)からインストールできるツールだとしているサイトがいくつかあったのですが、どこからインストールするのか分かりませんでした。　(2) このツールは OpenType フォントでも動作するでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> (1) 以前 ttfdump を使用したことがあったので例に挙げたのですが、どうやら ttfdump は Microsoft のページから削除されてしまったようです。 otfinfo を用いる方法へ置き換えましたので、ご確認ください。(2) otfinfo はドキュメントに書かれているとおり、 TrueType, OpenType に対応しています。私の環境でも正常に動作しているように見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。リンク先のダウンロードリンクから Windows 用のバイナリを入手することはできませんでしたが、LaTeX 関係のものを WSL Ubuntu にインストールすると諸々が使えるようになりました。ちなみに、得られた full name / Postscript name を使っても `@font-face` の指定が上手くいかなかったりしました（`url` による指定だと表示されるのに `local` による指定だと表示されないフォントがありました）が、とりあえず名前は取得できたので回答を承認しました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> Windows 用のバイナリは LCDF Typetools に書かれている[こちら](http://w32tex.org/index-ja.html)のページから入手出来ます。 / フォントはローカルにインストールされている必要があるため、もしかすると当該フォントがインストールされていないことで `local()` での参照が出来ず、 `url()` での参照は可能な状態になっているのかもしれません。また、私の環境ではフォントをインストールした後に、再起動をしなければ `local()` を使用してフォントを参照出来ませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

WSLのUbuntuが利用可能な環境とのことなので、**そこにfontconfigが入っていれば**(cairoやgdが依存しているので多くの環境で入っていそう、WSLのUbuntuのデフォルトはどうなっているかしないけど……)、`fc-query`でフォントの詳細が取得できそうです。

たとえば

```
$ fc-query /mnt/c/Windows/Fonts/meiryo.ttc |less
```

でメイリオの情報をダンプできました。

ただし、そのままだとcharsetのテーブルを全て表示したり同ファイルに含まれるのを全てならべたりするので`--format='%{family};%{fullname};%{postscriptname}\n'`を引数に指定するなどして情報を絞るのが質問の用途では実用的かもしれません。

(質問を目にした際にできるだろうなと思っていたものの確認できていなかったのをたまたま思い出して試してみたので回答として投稿します)